# Programmatically override value expression of composite-component’s attribute

Tags: java, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, composite-component, mojarra

I have written a wrapper component that in certain conditions overrides some attributes of its children.

In the *INVOKE_APPLICATION* phase (after an event), it calls `UIComponent#setValueExpression` on child components :

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext eLContext = ctx.getELContext();
ExpressionFactory factory = ctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
String newModelExpression = "#{newExpression}";
ValueExpression exp = factory.createValueExpression(eLContext, newModelExpression, Object.class);
((UIComponent) child).setValueExpression("model", exp);
```

Everything is fine **except with composite-componen**t as child.

With *composite-component*, the value expression is reset in the *RENDER_RESPONSE* phase and the initial expression is evaluated.

This happens in `CompositeComponentTagHandler$CompositeComponentRule$CompositeExpressionMetadata#applyMetaData`.

Is there a workaround for that ?

I’m using Payara with jsf-impl Mojarra 2.2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just called `UIComponent#setValueExpression` further to a `PreRenderViewEvent` processing.